# In Java 8 if map is having duplicate values getting duplicate values exceiption

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

The code is generating an `IllegalStateException: Duplicate key`, if there
are duplicate values in the list and while we are trying to extract map 
from list using java streams. If we define merge function in collect 
method, then the problem got resolved.

```
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
Employee e1 = new Employee(1,"aaaa","mgr",100666.99);
Employee e2 = new Employee(2,"bbbb","lead",90675.99);
Employee e3 = new Employee(3,"cccc","dev",77555.99);
Employee e4 = new Employee(4,"dddd","qe",63546.99);
Employee e5 = new Employee(5,"eeee","lead",90675.99);
Employee e6 = new Employee(6,"ffff","lead",90675.99);
Employee e7 = new Employee(7,"gggg","dev",90675.99);
Employee e8 = new Employee(8,"hhhh","qe",90675.99);
empList.add(e1);
empList.add(e2);
empList.add(e3);
empList.add(e4);
empList.add(e5);
empList.add(e6);
empList.add(e7);
empList.add(e8);

List<Department> deptList = new ArrayList<Department>();
Department d1 = new Department(1, "IT", 10);
Department d2 = new Department(2, "Sales", 20);
Department d3 = new Department(3, "HR", 30);
Department d4 = new Department(4, "Support", 40);
deptList.add(d1);
deptList.add(d2);
deptList.add(d3);
deptList.add(d4);

System.out.println("\n\n List of Leads Names :");

List<String> empNames = empList.stream().filter(emp -> "lead".equals(emp.job)).map(Employee::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
empNames.forEach(System.out::println);

Map<String,Double> jobSalMap = empList.stream().filter(emp -> "lead".equals(emp.job)).collect(Collectors.toMap(emp->emp.job,emp->emp.sal));

jobSalMap.forEach(new BiConsumer<String,Double>(){

    @Override
    public void accept(String arg0, Double arg1) {
        System.out.println(arg0 + " " + arg1);

    }

});

double sumOfLeadSal = empList.stream().filter(emp -> "lead".equals(emp.job)).mapToDouble(Employee::getSal).sum();

System.out.println(sumOfLeadSal);
```

Output :

```
List of Leads Names :
bbbb
eeee
ffff
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 90675.99
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.merge(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at com.zzar.practice.TestEmployee.main(TestEmployee.java:59)
```

Comment: This question don't have a correct format. We need a description of the problem, minimal code, good title and good tags. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting this exception for the exact code you have provided?

Comment: sure i'll post the correct format in future @Opsse

Comment: Sorry, @mks, it is fixed. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Why are you marking you entire question as quotation?

Comment: @Holger this is my first question on stack overflow, please correct me if there is any thing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: So you get exactly [what the documentation specifies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-): “*If the mapped keys contains duplicates …, an `IllegalStateException` is thrown when the collection operation is performed. If the mapped keys may have duplicates, use `toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)` instead*”…

Comment: I didn't understand the question. What's the problem? You've have solved the problem as you stated: *"If we define merge function in collect method, then the problem got resolved."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First solution: you need to know the constant salary by job title - no sum.**

You could use the toMap function with the merge operator:

```
Map<String, Double> mapByJob = empList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getJob, Employee::getSal, (sal1, sal2) -> sal1));

mapByJob .forEach((job, sal) -> System.out.println(job + " -> " + sal));
```

That will print the output:

> lead -> 90675.99

Note:

- Employee::getJob is 'equivalent' to your emp->emp.job
- But since the
  salary is not constant, I wouldn't use this solution (see second
  solution).

**Second solution: you need to know the salary by job title - with sum**

By summing the salary by job title, it becomes very handy information:

```
Map<String, Double> mapByJob = empList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getJob, Employee::getSal, (sal1, sal2) -> sal1+sal2));

mapByJob .forEach((job, sal) -> System.out.println(job + " -> " + sal));
```

The result is the following:

> qe -> 154222.98
>
> dev -> 168231.98
>
> mgr -> 100666.99
>
> lead -> 272027.97000000003

Java Doc: [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

Comment: @RazzeshCh you are welcome. Can you mark it as 'solution' if the answer pleases you?

Comment: I am unable to up vote your answer due to low reputation, please tell me how to mark your solution as answer in other ways, I am novice here.